# How can I keep an absolutely positioned element responsive when the browser is zoomed in or out?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a header image, and I've overlayed a title and subtitle to its bottom right. Using jQuery, their position responds on window resize, but not when zoomed in or out. I've heard that the window resize event can trigger when zooming in or out on certain browsers, but this doesn't seem to be the case. How can I solve this issue?

HTML

```
<img src='images/header-photo.png' id='image'>
<div id='title-container'>
    <h1 id='title' class='title-text'>Title</h1>
    <img src='images/logo.png' class='logo-img'>
</div>
<h2 id='subtitle'>Subtitle</h2>
```

CSS

```
#title-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 position: absolute;
}

#title {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#subtitle {
  position: absolute;
}

#title-container,
#subtitle {
  width: fit-content;
}

#image {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let titleLeft=()=>((parseFloat($('#image').css('margin-left')) + parseFloat($('#image').width())) * 0.65).toString().concat('px')
  let titleTop=()=>((parseFloat($('#image').css('margin-top')) + parseFloat($('#image').height())) * 0.6).toString().concat('px')
  let subtitleLeft=()=>((parseFloat(titleLeft())* 1.1).toString().concat('px'))
  let subtitleTop=()=>((parseFloat(titleTop())* 1.2).toString().concat('px'))

  $('#title-container').css({'left': titleLeft(), 'top': titleTop()})
  $('#subtitle').css({'left': subtitleLeft(), 'top': subtitleTop()})
  
  let resizeTitles=()=>{
    $('#title-container').css({'left': titleLeft(), 'top': titleTop()})
    $('#subtitle').css({'left': subtitleLeft(), 'top': subtitleTop()})
  }

  $(window).resize(resizeTitles())
})
```

Comment: You are calling `resizeTitles()` immediately when you only want to pass the function reference to the event listener ... `$(window).resize(resizeTitles)` so it gets called only when event occurs

Comment: That solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like charlietfl said in their comment, the issue was that I called resizeTiles rather than passing in the reference.

```
$(window).resize(resizeTitles)
```